# How to start powershell with a title and execute a command at the same time

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to start a powershell window with a title and execute a command at the same time. My line of code starts a powershell window with a title but does not execute the command in powershell (execute is in the cmd-window).

How can I fix the problem to get the execution in the powershell window I created with the title?

Thanks for helping me out

```
    start powershell -command "$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'WebWolf'" & java -jar .\webwolf-8.0.0.M25.jar --server.port=8090
```

Comment: Your [tag:powershell] command is enclosed within doublequotes, but you haven't included your [tag:java] execution command within them!

Comment: If you want to execute java inside of powershell window then add its command line inside of the `-command` parameter. BTW if you just need a window with a title `start` is enough.

Comment: Is it important that webwolf.exe runs in a PowerShell host? If not, `start "WebWolf" java -jar .\webwolf-8.0.0.M25.jar --server.port=8090` would run it in a cmd.exe shell with the title you desire.

Comment: `start powershell -noExit -command "$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle ='WebWolf' & java -jar .\webgoat-server-8.0.0.M25.jar --server.port=8090"` is not working either now I get a error message: & is not a valid token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following syntax should work for you. Just swap out the -Command text with your java commands.

```
start "WebWolf" powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "reg.exe /?"
```

[image: Example of working code]

Comment: If anyone want to execute command in **powershell**,you can use this command:`cmd.exe /c "start  ""my app"" powershell.exe -NoExit -Command  ""dotnet myapp"""`
`