# PowerShell how to start a process in new window giving the new window a name

Tags: powershell

How can I start a command (i.e. another program) in PowerShell in a new window giving that window a specific name? I want the equivalent of what you get in cmd by simply saying

```
start "window-title" command/program [arguments]
```

I googled around and so far only found misc. suggestions like generating a code-block containing "$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle='Your Title Here'" plus that command to execute which is then executed by the new process or starting classic cmd.exe (with the syntax above) and passing it the remaining arguments and similar constructions. These all appear absurdly complex to me.

If I need cmd.exe to achieve such an presumably simple task, why should I then ever bother to switch to PowerShell?

Is simply giving a new process' window a decent name really such a mountain climbing experience in PowerShell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start powershell with a title and execute a command at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379763/how-to-start-powershell-with-a-title-and-execute-a-command-at-the-same-time)

Comment: If you want to lancuh from the powershell and not the cmd, use `cmd.exe /c "start  ""my app"" powershell.exe -NoExit -Command  ""dotnet myapp"""`

Comment: Simplest workaround is to just use `cmd` as an intermediary launcher: `cmd /c 'start "window-title" program arguments'`